# Error parsing LocalFile: Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, flutter, android-manifest

Compañeros, he venido resolviendo algunos problemas de una App que tengo gracias a ustedes.

Ahora la app ya compila y se instala, sin embargo la app no abre, se cierra inmediatamente y no da ningun mensaje de error, he corrido flutter doctor y da el siguiente mensaje:

> Error parsing LocalFile: 'C:\Users\Marva\Desktop\Next Hour\Nexthour
> Mobile App Flutter Files\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'
> Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and
> try again.

No entiendo que pueda ser, este es mi AndroidManifest.xml esperando me puedan ayudar porque no entiendo que pueda ser.

Gracias de antemano.

```
    <application
        android:label="Nextrim"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        <activity
            android:name="com.amazon.identity.auth.device.workflow.WorkflowActivity"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <!-- android:host must use the full package name found in Manifest General Attributes -->
                <data
                    android:host="${applicationId}"
                    android:scheme="amzn"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
           
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
                android:value="true"
                />
                
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Facebook Login -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--Facebook Login End-->

        <!-- For Braintree payment gateway start-->

        <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- For Braintree payment gateway start-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ENTER_GOOGLE_AD_APPLICATION_ID_HERE"/>
        
        <!--For Download button start-->
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- disable default Initializer -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>

        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
            android:exported="false">

            <meta-data
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="5" />
        </provider>
        <!--For Download button end-->
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Le falta una '>' al final de su application etiqueta al principio del archivo.

```
<application
    android:label="Nextrim"
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

debe terminar con '>'

```
<application
    android:label="Nextrim"
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

y también falta la etiqueta de 'manifest' al principio del archivo.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="yourpackagename">
```

Si tiene una versión anterior de su manifest.xml, debe consultarlo para ver cómo se veía antes de que se corrompiera.